# Shifting controls on view controller

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, ios6

I am generating dynamic textfeilds as per number entered in a textfeild but the problem is the remaining controls gets hidden by the generated textfeilds  i tried to put remaining controls on one another view and tried to shift that view but it doesn't worked for me as a newbie to objective c world i am not able to figure this out
please help me out
thanks in advace..[image: dynamic generation]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Moving the other controls by passing a `CGRect` with `rect.origin.y` increased to the `setFrame` method isn't that difficult.

Comment: What's about UIScrollView ?

Comment: i tried this      ViewBottom=[[UIView alloc]init];
            [ViewBottom setFrame:CGRectMake(10,txtFldFrame1.frame.origin.y+200, 300, 120)];
            [ScrollLag addSubview:ViewBottom];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this and it worked for me

```
CGPoint controlsCenter = ViewBottom.center;
if(Pointsvalue > 5)
{
controlsCenter.y += txtFldFrame1.frame.origin.y+20;
ViewBottom.center = controlsCenter;

[ScrollLag addSubview:ViewBottom];
}

[ScrollLag setContentSize:(CGSizeMake(0, controlsCenter.y+100))];
```

here ScrollLag is my scroll and Viewbottom is my view.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use `UITableView` to display so many `UITextFields`, because in current realization if u pick 9+ points, you won't see `UITextFields` below the screen.

Comment: Cant i do something with existing one as the app is almost complete.

Comment: Yes, you need to create UITableView with [custom cells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/tableview_iphone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7-SW18) (every cell will contain 2 textfields (for your x and f(x) columns)). So after that you'll need just set table size. I recommend you quick look at [this apple guide, about tables programming](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html).

Comment: there is a way without tableview i have posted my code check it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should use UIScrollView and set it's contentSize large enough to contain all your textField.

Comment: you should calculate textfield's X Y position dynamically and  add calculate button at last with maximum y value ... and you should keep content size large enough to content your button